# Using Selenium 2 without a Test Framework?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit, webdriver

I've been messing around with Selenium 2 for a while now, with the purpose of running automated tests
My goal is to write tests in Java and run each test in different browsers, simultaneously if possible.
My question to you is: Why use a Testing framework such as JUnit for this? It appears to be the most commonly used method for doing this. However, JUnit makes it much harder to work with multiple threads. I tried to just use plain old java without a testing framework, and this appears to work just fine. So I ask you, Is there a reason I should use JUnit? MultiThreadding is a much easier task without it. Also, are there easy ways to multithread with JUnit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The benefit of JUnit is that it generates a nice report and there are plenty of tools that integrate with it (like most IDEs). You might want to check TestNG, which is another unit testing framework, but has mutithreaded support.

Comment: Is the 'nice report' worth it tho?
Similar things can be done with some simple try-catch's for NoSuchElementException?

Comment: If you don't think you need to use junit, then don't use it. But you might want to check that you're not experiencing the [Not-Invented-Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) syndrome.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can coerce JUnit into working with multiple parallel threads. Refer [this best practices article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1221-junit.html?page=1) on how to write multi-threaded tests using JUnit. There are [JUnit extensions](http://groboutils.sourceforge.net/testing-junit/using_mtt.html) which will help you in this. So that should not be a big problem. Otherwise you can start off with TestNG

However if I were you I would be more concerned if WebDriver plays well in multi-threaded test environment. There are [several](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3905) [open](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2319) [issues](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4320) pertaining to multi-threaded use (IE driver, especially).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be using TestNG www.testng.org.  It makes writing tests a breeze, and probably  does everything you are writing from hand in Java.  Why reinvent the wheel ?